# Scala/Akka How do you reference the message being received?

Tags: scala, akka, case-class

I have a Java program that I must implement in Scala, but I am extremely new to Scala. After reading a number of SO question & answers as well as reading through a number of Google-retrieved resources on case classes, I am still having trouble grasping how to acquire a reference to the message I received? Example code is below:

```
case class SpecialMessage(key: Int) {
  val id: Int = Main.idNum.getAndIncrement().intValue()   
  def getId(): Int = {
    return id
  }
}
```

Then in another class's receive I am trying to reference that number with:

```
def receive() = {
  case SpecialMessage(key) {
    val empID = ?? getId() // Get the id stored in the Special Message

    // Do stuff with empID
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out what to put on the right sight of empID = in order to get that id. Is this really simple, or something that isn't normally done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are 2 ways to do what you want, pick the one that suits best

```
case msg: SpecialMessage => {
  val empID = msg.getId() // Get the id stored in the Special Message
  // Do stuff with empID
}
case msg @ SpecialMessage(key) => {
  val empID = msg.getId() // Get the id stored in the Special Message
  // Do stuff with empID
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it would be that easy, but I couldn't find information on it anywhere. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Pim's answer is good.
But maybe you can modify the structure of SpecialMessage like

```
  case class SpecialMessage(key: Int,val id: Int = Main.idNum.getAndIncrement().intValue())
```

so you can get id directly from pattern matching.

```
def receive() = {
  case SpecialMessage(key, empID) {
     // Do stuff with empID
  }
}
```